# Status display module

Tags: javascript, modules

I've developed a template to modularize JavaScript code I write for client work. The example below is a simple class with 1 attribute and 3 functions.

Rationale:

- Standardized constructor to add or modify settings/ options
- Functions as variables used later to return only "public" functions, all else are private
- Using local "call" variable to easily replace functions in unit testing

Are there any improvements you can recommend or general best practices to look for in terms of improvement?

```
var dataStatus = function( constructorOptions )
{
    "use strict";

    var options = {
        displayId: 'dataStatus',
        statii: {
            'settingUp': {
                tooltip: 'Setting Up...',
                color: '808080'
            },
            'loading': {
                tooltip: 'Data Loading...',
                color: '99ee90'
            },
            'loaded': {
                tooltip: 'Data Loaded',
                color: '006400'
            },
            'changed': {
                tooltip: 'Data Changed',
                color: '8b0000'
            },
            'saving': {
                tooltip: 'Saving...',
                color: 'ffd700'
            }
        },
        defaultStatus: 'settingUp'
    };

    var local = {
        status: false
    };

    var init = function( optionsToSet )
    {
        jQuery.extend( options, optionsToSet);

        call.setStatus( options.defaultStatus );
        return this;
    };


    var inject = function (functionToReplace, injectedFunction)
    {
        call[functionToReplace] = injectedFunction;
        return injectedFunction;
    };



    var getStatus = function()
    {
        return local.status;
    };

    var setStatus = function( status, signal )
    {
        local.status = status;
        if (typeof signal == 'undefined' || signal != false){
            call.signal( call.getStatus() );
        }
    };

    var signal = function ( status ){
        if (status in options.statii){
            jQuery( '#' + options.displayId )
                .html( '<i class="fa fa-circle" title="' + options.statii[status].tooltip + '"></i>')
                .css( 'color', '#' + options.statii[status].color )
                .css( 'background-color', '#ffffff');
        }
    };


    var call = {
        init: init,
        options: options,
        inject: inject,
        getStatus: getStatus,
        setStatus: setStatus,
        signal: signal
    };

    if(typeof myPublicTestNamespace == "undefined"){//http://stackoverflow.com/a/9172377/123594
        return {
            init: init,
            getStatus: getStatus,
            setStatus: setStatus,
            signal: signal
        };
    }else{
        return call;
    };

    init( constructorOptions );
};
```

Comment: @200_success thanks for the edit. I hope your edit improves views, the answers I'm after are about the modularization of my code, not about what it does. Do you still think your edit will help?

Comment: Every Code Review question is principally about your posted code in general, even if you have specific concerns about it. The title needs to reflect the purpose of your code, [by site policy](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2454/9357). (If you want to discuss general guiding principles instead of your code, then [programmers.se] would be the place for that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has somewhat inconsistent styling which can inhibit readability and prevent the code from looking crisp and professional. For example, some of your function definitions have braces on the next line others don't. Some of your function definitions and calls put spaces between parenthesis `var signal = function ( status ){`, and some don't `var inject = function (functionToReplace, injectedFunction)`.

Also, I don't believe that the last line `init( constructorOptions );` is executing because you return from the constructor in both the `if` and `else` blocks right above it.

That said, using closures to keep private functions private is a great idea.

As for the modularity, while returning a separate object for for testing is a truly fascinating idea, my gut instinct goes against it. I find it somewhat troublesome because it violates cohesion with your constructor really doing two things: creating a dataStatus object and creating a dataStatus test object. This introduces room for bugs if future functions aren't properly assigned to both the real and test object. To catch these bugs, you'd want to write a test case that ensures the test object shares all the same functions as the real object. (i.e. `call` could have extra functions but it must also have each one that a normal dataStatus would)

I'd recommend eliminating `call` and if needed to use `this` instead. Although it might be best to just call the functions directly.

```
var init = function () {
    jQuery.extend(options, optionsToSet);

    setStatus(options.defaultStatus); // just call setStatus directly
    return this;
}
```

You can still do your testing by dissecting the methods you want from the real object.

```
var realObj = new dataStatus (options);
var testObj = {
    setStatus : realObj.setStatus,
    getStatus : function () {},
    signal : function () {}
};
```

Private functions should be tested through the testing of public functions, but in your case the only private function is for changing functions when testing.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you're set on testing your private functions--and I can fully understand how it could be worth it--you ought to to take care of a few things.

First, make sure the test object and the real object have the same functions. You could write a test case that checks that their functions are the same, but it may be best to just write the private functions directly as properties of the call object:

```
var call = {};

call.init = function () {
    // ...
}
call.inject = function () {
    // ...
}
call.getStatus = function () {
    // ...
}

// ...

if (/* determine if your unit testing each function */) {
    return call;
}
else {
    return {
        init: call.init,
        getStatus: call.getStatus,
        setStatus: call.setStatus,
        signal: call.signal
    };
}
```

Secondly, you will want to also test the real object. You could have millions of test cases for your test object, but since your real object isn't your test object, the real object might still break.

Comment: The styling is all opinion based. His style will not affect how ECMAScript is interpreted; However, you make a very strong point about using this instead of call.

Comment: True, it does not matter to the interpreter. But while it may be an opinion that _inconsistently_ styled code is harder to read, it's a fact that some developers will complain about it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the style. I'm mainly writing PHP, so there I have PSR-2 to stick to - I find  it great to eliminate discussions about which exact style is best. I try to apply it to JavaScript as well, because I know no style guide for it. Any pointers welcome

Comment: @John Dawson regarding returning a separate object, in my opinion unit testing should not be black box based, but also test private methods. I prefer more test coverage of under-engineered classes than less test cases for well engineered classes. But it may just be because I'm not as experienced with JS as with backend work.

Comment: @jdog Yeah, particulars of which styling convention is not as important, but it's best to write a project using the same style. Surprisingly, I've found JavaScript libraries to be pretty consistent with style at least with variable naming and bracket placement. If you're looking for js style guides, I'd recommend looking into http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp or http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html. There's also a pretty nifty online js interpreter at https://jsfiddle.net/ that has a 'tidy' feature that will standardize code you've written.

Comment: One more question: Using this instead of call: Isn't this already defined? What information would I lose if I used this instead?

Comment: @jdog You're right, 'this' is the object that is returned when a function is called with the new operator. Sorry to be unclear! By using 'this' instead of 'call', I meant to entirely get rid of the testing private function capability. The idea was that wherever you needed to call functions from the object to use 'this' instead, for example: instead of using "call.init()" to use "this.init()". Probably what would be even better than all that is to just call the function directly: "init()"

Answer (score 1):

### Spelling

*status*, like *sinus*, has an -es plural, not an -i - hence, the plural you want for your `statii` variable is `statuses`.

### Spacing

Be consistent in the whitespace you use. In some methods, you're using the pattern on padding whitespace on both sides:

```
var methodName = function( argument1, argument2 )
```

In at least one, you've missed the padding and have this instead:

```
var methodName = function(argument1, argument2)
```

I also recommend padding space around `else`: `}else{` should be `} else {` for readability.

It's a minor point, but consistency in your minor points makes consistency in the major points more natural.

### Naming

Generally good variable naming, but beware that `local` is a reserved keyword in ES6.

### Equality

JavaScript has two equality checks: `==` and `===`. I'll spare you the extensive and weird details of each of them, but suffice to say that double-equals is rough equality (i.e. `0 == false`) and triple-equals is exact equality.

You should use `===` when comparing with strings, booleans, undefined or null.

### Attribution

It's good that you're attributing where your code came from with that comment hyperlink to SO. However, you also need to include *and hyperlink* the author's name.

Comment: === checks type as well as the value. == checks just the value.

Answer (score 0):

strict mode is only supported in:

- Internet Explorer from version 10.
- Firefox from version 4.
- Chrome from version 13.
- Safari from version 5.1.
- Opera from version 12.

You class seems dependent on JQUERY, you should make a check to ensure JQUERY has been loaded, if not load it dynamically.

```
if(typeof myPublicTestNamespace == "undefined"){//http://stackoverflow.com/a/9172377/123594
        return {
            init: init,
            getStatus: getStatus,
            setStatus: setStatus,
            signal: signal
        };
    }else{
        return call;
    };
```

does not need an else return. just return like:

```
if(typeof myPublicTestNamespace == "undefined"){//http://stackoverflow.com/a/9172377/123594
        return {
            init: init,
            getStatus: getStatus,
            setStatus: setStatus,
            signal: signal
        };
    }
    return call;
```

i am not entirely sure `init( constructorOptions );` will ever be called due to your returns above it. If so, i would consider it bad practice.

---

from @Josh Dawson

> I'd recommend **eliminating call and using this instead**. That way you
>   can do your testing by disecting the methods you want from the real
>   object.

```
var realObj = new dataStatus (options); var testObj = {
     setStatus : realObj.setStatus,
     getStatus : function () {},
     signal : function () {}
};
```

> Private functions should be tested through the testing of public functions, but your only private
>   function is for changing functions when testing.